# Continuous dependence of spectrum of Fredholm integral operator on parameters

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, integral-equations

Let $(X,\mathcal B(X),\lambda)$ be some Euclidean space $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. Suppose we have a Fredholm integral operator $$T:L^1(X)\to L^1(X):f(\cdot)\mapsto\int_XK(\cdot,y)f(y)\ \mathrm dy,$$ where $K$ is some uniformly bounded kernel, *that is not necessarily symmetric*. Now suppose that we can find a sequence of kernels $K^m$ converging to $K$ in $L^1(X^2)$ corresponding to Fredholm integral operators $T^m$. It is well-known that if $\rho(T)<1$, where $\rho(T)$ denotes the spectral radius of $T$, that the corresponding Fredholm integral equation of the second kind
$$f=g+Tf$$ admits a unique solution for any $g\in L^1$, that the solutions depends continuously on the initial conditions, that the resolvent can be given by a Liouville Neumann series, and furthermore that the resolvent $r$ depends continuously on the initial conditions. In particular, it follows from Corollary 9.3.12 from Gripenberg, Londen, Staffans, *Volterra Integral and Functional Equations* that for $m$ sufficiently large, $T^m$ admits a resolvent $r^m$, and that $r^m\to r$ in $L^1(X)$.

Can we, somehow, conclude from this that given $\epsilon>0$, we can find some $M$, such that for $m\geq M$, $\rho(T^m)<\rho(T)+\epsilon$? Intuitively, such a results seems to make sense, but I have trouble proving it. It seems that the answer is affirmative when we force the kernel $K$ to be symmetric, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4475. However, in the application I have in mind, I was hoping to do without assumptions like self-adjointness, normality, etc. Also, I was hoping there was maybe a more direct approach.

Any help or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: This looks a bit weird to me. Surely you need more than $L^1(X^2)$ convergence of the kernels to guarantee that the $T^m$ are even well defined operators on $L^1$, since they could be unbounded functions.

Comment: In the textbook you linked, it looks as though they assume operator convergence of the associated fredholm operators, so I will work with that for now. In this case, the result should follow from the following: Pick $|\lambda|>\rho(T)+\epsilon$. Then, you have $T^m-\lambda=T-\lambda+(T-T^m)=(Id-(T-T^m)R(T,\lambda))(T-\lambda)$. If $\|T-T^m\|<\frac{1}{\|R(T,\lambda)\|}$, then this is a product of invertible terms, and so invertible. Hence, you just have to pick $M$ so that $\|T-T^m\|<\inf_{|\lambda|\geq \rho(T)+\epsilon}\|R(T,\lambda)\|^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for helpful comments! This may be very easy, but how exactly can I know for sure that $\inf_{|\lambda|\geq\rho(T)+\epsilon}\|R(T,\lambda)\|^{-1}<\infty$?

Comment: I guess you need that $\inf_{|\lambda|\geq \rho(T)+\epsilon}\|R(T,\lambda)\|^{-1}>0$ for this particular application? This follows because the resolvent of a bounded operator is in general a continuous function, who's operator norm decays as it tends to infinity. The continuity follows from the resolvent identity $R(T,\lambda)-R(T,\mu)=(\lambda-\mu)R(T,\lambda)R(T,\mu)$, whereas the decay follows from $\|R(T,\lambda)\|=\|\sum_i \lambda^{-(i+1)}T^i \| \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda|-\|T\|}$ for $\lambda$ large enough.

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended to ask, indeed! Thanks again!!